# LEFT JOIN isn't working as expected while retrieving data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables, named `subscriptions` and `tags`.  Once in a month I will have to create tags for each order.

I have to list subscriptions without a tag for the given month (2011-10-01 or 2011-09-01 etc).  This query returns 0 records:

```
   SELECT s.id, s.active, s.status 
     FROM asw_subscriptions as s 
LEFT JOIN asw_tags as t ON s.id = t.subscription_id 
    WHERE t.subscription_id IS NULL 
      AND t.deliveryDate = '2011-10-01' 
      AND s.status = '2' 
      AND s.active = '1' 
 ORDER BY s.id DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 25
```

#### Table Structure

---

**subscriptions**  = id (int / auto), active (enum : 0,1), status (enum : 0,1)

**tags** = id (int / auto), deliveryDate (date), tagNumber

Comment: Why do you say "given month" but provide a specific date?  Have you considered that there isn't data to support what you're looking for?

Comment: There was data that's why I had to open a question (: I just couldn't find a way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in clausule

```
t.deliveryDate = '2011-10-01' AND
```

You have not record on the left because condition 'IS NULL' eliminates LEFT JOIN'ed records. 
So, above condition will eliminate all join products, because will never be true (there will be always null in t.deliveryDate.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.active, s.status 
     FROM asw_subscriptions as s 
WHERE s.status = '2' 
      AND s.active = '1' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM asw_tags as t
         WHERE s.id = t.subscription_id
         AND t.deliveryDate = '2011-10-01'          
      )
 ORDER BY s.id DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: What is the solution to this?

Comment: Thank you that saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are checking the tag date on the same query that checks the existence of a tag.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.active, s.status 
FROM
    asw_subscriptions as s
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT subscription_id
        FROM asw_tags
        WHERE deliveryDate = '2011-10-01'
    ) as t ON s.id = t.subscription_id 
WHERE 
    t.subscription_id IS NULL
    AND s.status = '2'
    AND s.active = '1' 
ORDER BY s.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realize that specifying condition under WHERE - you implement INNER JOIN logic, It is not what you have expected. So place entire WHERE section under ON of OUTER JOIN:

```
 ... ON s.id = t.subscription_id 
 AND t.subscription_id IS NULL AND 
 t.deliveryDate = '2011-10-01' AND 
 s.status = '2' AND 
 s.active = '1'
```

Comment: WHERE clause filtration on an OUTER join does not "make it an INNER JOIN".  Second, only one of the **t** criteria needs to move up - you wouldn't move the `s` stuff because third you're aren't understanding that LEFT JOIN/IS NULL requires a filtration clause in the WHERE clause